# WP7 VB.NET Tombstone listbox items

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7.1

I have a listbox that contains custom items. A stackpanel with 2 textboxes.

So how do I store those items into phoneapplicationservice.current.state so that I can have them back when I recover from tombstone?

By the way how to put them back too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you save:

- The underlying source of the ListBox (or the loaded items and index offsets if using virtualised data)
- The selected item index (if needed)
- The scrolloffset of the Listboxes interal scrollviewer (but be careful if using virtualised data)